# Subset product problems (one "easy" one "difficult")

Tags: algorithms, sets

This question is from an exam preparation that I have to demonstrate to my teacher to show him that I understood the topic thoroughly .

Given a set $S$ of integers with $n$ elements, an integer $z$ and an integer $k \leq 2$, sketch an algorithm that checks whether there are $k$ elements in $S$ of which the product equals $z$.

I need to find two algorithms: one that solves the problem in $O(n^k)$ and the other one that solves the problem in $O(n^{k-1}\log n)$.

How can I do this? Could you help me with some hints? Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? In general, if you're converting from $O(n)$ to $O(\log n)$ you're going to be using either trees, or recursive divide and conquer to get the speed boost somewhere. How would you solve it by brute-force? What kinds of optimizations on that can you think of? Can you think of ways to divide this into smaller subproblems?

Comment: i know that the ... log (n) comes from sorting the set first.

Comment: actually my problem is already that i don't know how to get all the k-element subsets from the set. i would need to permute it...? brute-force would be to get all the possible subsets and then multiply the elements and then check whether it equals k.

Comment: From an exam you're writing? Is what you're doing considered ethical by the "institution" that is administering this exam?

Comment: no i did not even write that. some admin edited that. this is the exam that we got for practising and i need to "demonstrate" these algorithms to my teacher so i need to understand them thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint1:** How many subsets of $k$ elements can be selected from an $n$-elementary set? Try to enumerate them efficiently and check if their product equals $z$ alongside.

**Hint2:** Suppose you know (enumerate) all the products of the $k-1$-elementary subsets of $S$. Can you then check for every subset fast, if there is one remaining element in $S$ that is missing to give you the right product? Try to sort the elements in $S$ in a preprocessing step to achieve the speed-up.

Comment: i still do not understand the second hint. how can i do this - z/(x1,x2,xk-1)?

Comment: Exactly, search for the element $z/(x_1 x_2 \cdots x_{k-1})$ in $S=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_{k-1}\}$. You know about binary search, right?

Comment: yes. so i do sth similar to https://gist.github.com/doph/3118596 to find the k-elementary subsets?